# android java character different from non-android java

Tags: java, android, string, unicode, utf-8

i have this RandomAccessFile object that reads bytes from a file and stores them into a byte array. they should compose a hebrew letter string.
if i debug them in JAVA on a desktop, then for 4 bytes in hex i get, for example:

```
data[0]=E7
data[1]=FA
data[2]=E5
data[3]=EC
```

(so, 1 byte length each which makes sense)

when i construct a String str from them i get:

```
str[0]=\u05D7
str[1]=\u05EA
str[2]=\u05D5
str[3]=\u05DC
```

which are the correct unicoded hebrew letters and the string print out just fine. are they 2 bytes length each?

when i do the same debugging on an Android device i get the same "data" byte array but the "str" string is 4 identical bytes which reads out as 4 question mark.

my question is: how can java take 1 byte and "know" it's hebrew, and how can i do it in Android just the same?

thanks

code:

```
iDefLength=4;
RandomAccessFile R = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");       
R.read(bDefinition, 0, iDefLength);
this.sDef = new String(bDefinition);
```

Comment: And your code is? Have you checked the javadoc for the bytes to string conversion method you're using, because I'm pretty sure it's all described there.

Comment: What's the locale of your desktop?  Could it be that your desktop JVM's default encoding is something that can handle the Hebrew, but the Android's JVM's default encoding is something like `ISO-8859-1`?

Comment: Yes, that code is using the default encoding, so I'm near certain a difference in default encoding is responsible for the difference you're seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your question: No, Java cannot take 1 byte and know it's Hebrew, or any other encoding.

While it's possible to make an encoding guess by doing stuff like looking at many/all bytes in the file and guessing the encoding by looking at byte frequencies (I believe Microsoft does this with IE), obviously that can't work on a single byte.

Comment: i've added the nessecary code for understanding. I have tried to build the string with new String(bDefinition,"Cp1255") and it worked. BUT i want to write something that will work for every language. is it possible? obviously you need more than one byte to determine the language, but when i debugged it did it somehow and i want to know what is needed.

Comment: The easiest way is to know the encoding of the files you're opening. Either always use the same encoding, or store the file-encoding association somewhere, or ask the user to specify the encoding when opening the file.

Comment: It didn't "know" what the encoding was.  It was a coincidence that the file was created with the same encoding as your desktop's default encoding.  (Of course it wasn't really a coincidence -- I'm guessing you created the files on your desktop and used the default encoding for the creation, too.  So of course it was the same encoding that the read-in program was expecting :)

Comment: um... sort of. actually it's a dicitionary app and i didn't create the data file, but i tried hebrew first because it always hard to grasp on the encoding part and i speak it so...